# Property 'message' does not exist on type 'ErrorRequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.ts(2339)?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

Hello I created a custom error middleware handler in my node typescript app

and getting an error that message does not exist on type ErrorRquestHandler

```
const errorHandler = (
  err: ErrorRequestHandler, 
  _req: Request, 
  res: Response, 
  _next: NextFunction
) => {
  const statusCode = res.statusCode === 200 ? 500 : res.statusCode;
  res.status(statusCode);
  res.json({
    message: err.message,
    stack: err.stack
  })
}
```

I've tried uncommenting "typeRoots" and "types" in my tsconfig.json file and still same error.

What is causing this error?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have an error handler that is declared correctly but the type of the `err` parameter is wrong, instead, the `const errorHandler` itself should be typed with `ErrorRequestHandler` so the parameters are inferred.

The type `ErrorRequestHandler` is [defined as follows in DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts#L75-L86):

```js
export type ErrorRequestHandler<
  P = ParamsDictionary,
  ResBody = any,
  ReqBody = any,
  ReqQuery = ParsedQs,
  Locals extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>
> = (
  err: any,
  req: Request<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery, Locals>,
  res: Response<ResBody, Locals>,
  next: NextFunction,
) => void;
```

Suggesting that your code should look as follows:

```js
const errorHandler: ErrorRequestHandler = (
  err, 
  _req, 
  res, 
  _next
) => {
  const statusCode = res.statusCode === 200 ? 500 : res.statusCode;
  res.status(statusCode);
  res.json({
    message: err.message,
    stack: err.stack
  })
}
```

Note that change to `const errorHandler` to be typed with `ErrorRequestHandler` meaning you can drop the explicitly typed parameters on the function (unless you have the tsconfig option enabled that requires them). Do note that now `err` is typed as `err: any` thanks to `ErrorRequestHandler`, you should probably test it to ensure it's an error first before using `err.message` as its also not guaranteed to be a type of `Error`. The compiler will allow it however as it's typed as `any`, to be safe I would recommend you test explicitly for errors using the [built-in node utility api](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utiltypesisnativeerrorvalue) before making use of properties.

```js
if (isNativeError(err)) {
  // use err.message
} else {
  // handle unexpected error
  // or send generic unknown error response
}
```